# jQuery Tooltip plugin error

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, tooltip

i have written this code to apply 'jQuery Tooltip plugin' to ajax loaded elements.

i mean the row i want to show tooltip on its mouseover is loaded into page by ajax.
here's the code:

```
$("[id^=pane]").delegate("[id^=comm]","mouseover",function() {

   $(this).tooltip({

      // each trashcan image works as a trigger
      tip: "#tooltip",
      // custom positioning
      position: "center right",
      // move tooltip a little bit to the right
      offset: [0, 15],
      // there is no delay when the mouse is moved away from the trigger
      delay: 0
  }).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: "down", bounce: true } });

});
```

the tooltip is shown when mouseover but firebug report this error:

"$(this).tooltip({tip: "#tooltip", position: "center right", offset: [0, 15], delay: 0}).dynamic is not a function"

is it because of using $(this) ???

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you haven't loaded the `dynamic` function.  From [the jQuery tools documentation](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/dynamic.html):

> the dynamic plugin and the slide effect are not included in the standard jQuery Tools distribution. You must download a [custom combination](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html#combine) to include those effects.

---

Furthermore, you don't need your `delegate` call.  You are redoing the `tooltip` creation on every mouseover.  You only need to do it once; the plugin will handle the events internally.

```
$("[id^=pane] [id^=comm]").tooltip({/*...*/})
       .dynamic({/*...*/});
```

This selects all elements with ids beginning `comm` that are children of elements with ids beginning `pane`.  Note that adding appropriate classes to all these elements would speed up your selection significantly.

Comment: thank you,but dynamic is included in my jquery tools file.i select it in addition to tooltip from its site. and i use delegate because i add my elements with ajax .

Comment: `delegate` isn't a catch-all solution for when you add elements dynamically. Every time you mouseover an element, you are calling the `tooltip` function, which is bound to be computationally expensive. Second, it's pretty hard to debug a problem by guesswork. If you could provide a (non-)working example of your code, that would make things 16.34 times easier.

Answer (score 0):

it is solved now,i searched more in google and found the solution.

here it is:

```
$("[id^=pane]").delegate("[id^=comm]:not(.hastooltip)","mouseover",function() {
    $(this).addClass("hastooltip").tooltip({
        tip: "#tooltip",
        position: "bottom center",
        offset: [-10, 0],
        delay: 0
    }).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: "down", bounce: true } }).mouseover();
});
```